# Matrix of averages from array

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, average

Right now i have an array that is three dimensions.  I have 200 rows, 200 columns and 24 "slices" in the third dimension

```
dim=c(200,200,24)
```

What I need is an average of the slices resulting in a new matrix.  I need a 200 by 200 matrix and the values are the result of averaging up the appropriate slices.  So in the location that would be row 1, col 1, I need the average of all the row 1's and col 1's from my array.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one attempt using a simple example:

```
test <- 1:8
dim(test) <- c(2,2,2)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Get your answer:

```
apply(test,c(1,2),mean)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    4    6
```

Comment: Thanks! That did exactly what I needed.  Is there a way I can select specific slices I want averaged?  Suppose I just want the first three averaged.

Comment: @user2113499 - try `apply(test[,,1:3],c(1,2),mean)` - the part you change is here: `test[,,insert.vector.of.numbers.of.slices.here]`